# Exponential stability under a global coordinate transformation

Tags: control-engineering, control-theory, stability

Consider a system of the form
\begin{equation}
\Sigma\colon\ \dot{x}=f(x),
\end{equation}
where $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $f\colon \mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^n$ is a sufficiently smooth function vanishing at the origin. Assume that $\Sigma$ has a *globally exponentially stable* equilibrium at $x=0$. Now apply a global coordinate transformation
\begin{equation}
z=T(x),
\end{equation}
where $T\colon \mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^n$, $T(0)=0$ is a global $\mathcal{C}^1$ diffeomorphism. Accordingly, we obtain the transformed system
\begin{equation}
\Sigma^\prime \colon\ \dot{z}=g(z):=\frac{\partial T(x)}{\partial x}f(x)\bigg|_{x=T^{-1}(z)}.
\end{equation}
**Question:** Is $\Sigma^\prime$ globally exponentially stable at $z=0$?

Comment: Maybe you should ask this in math.stackexchange.com

Comment: This looks like a homework question. Linearization and eigenvalue analysis show that $\Sigma'$ is also exponentially stable at $z=0$. Note that you do not really need $\frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial x^2}$.